# Git - Is there any way to group commits, so they will have to be cherry picked/merged together?

Tags: git, version-control

in the company I work for we normally include the name of the jira task in the commit message so we can keep track of which commits relate to which task when cherry picking. this methodology relies on developer discipline so it feels error prone. for example you could cherry pick a feature without knowing there was a later bug fix you should have cherry picked together with it, if the developer forgets to mention the original task in the bug-fix commit message. Also, git commits and jira tasks are uncorrelated. A bug-fix jira task might mention the original task, but the developer can still forget to mention it in the commit message, making it more plausible the original branch will be cherry picked without the fix.

so, is there a way to connect all these?
The question mentions git as this is the version control we're using but if this available in another VCS I'd also love to know.
Thanks.

P.S - squashing is usually not an option since you'd be squashing a lot of unrelated commits together with the ones you'd want to group.

Comment: What about a branch ?

Comment: This is generally what a "pull request" is for: a group of commits that should be applied to some branch as a unit. It sounds like there are some opportunities in your organization for some automated policy (e.g., rejecting commits that don't contain a Jira reference), and possibly some opportunities to work on a more structured workflow.

Comment: I was referring to the situation when a feature was already merged but later you've found a bug and need to declare sort of a "dependency" so that if a manager, unknowing about the bug decides to include the original commits into a new version branch he's making, would also have to include the bug-fix commits along with them. relying on memory/conventions seems unreliable. optimally there would be a git command that would allow you to group commits, or at least have a higher level tool to manage this Jira-Git-Jenkins-WhateverTool work

Comment: @Ôrel you mean committing the bug fix directly into the original feature branch? this is usually a problem as the bug fix is done branching out of where master currently is, which is far ahead of where the original feature branch was

Comment: Git certainly does not have such a thing, and is probably the wrong "level" for this. But if you fix bugs by applying the fix "just after" the finished feature in the first place, then merge the fix into each place that needs it, you get this for free without requiring any special Git feature. See [Raymond Chen's blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325).

Comment: You can't rewrite commits that already are merged, so there's no way to have past commits reference future commits. But the future ones can obviously reference past ones if you wish, for example this is [common in the Git repo](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45350aeb11e0d8b5f76a121dfb9fc053af8e6042). I'd probably use your bug tracking tool though, since I assume you can still link commits to a bug in your tool even if it wasn't linked at the time the commit was created?

Comment: @TTT that's what we're doing, I just don't like that this information is spread between a lot of different places such as Jira and comments in various Git commits. feels like it could benefit from automatic management by some platform/tool.